# Vim:E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off

Tags: neovim

Im currently using `nvim` when I try to use `control + p` to search for files and a try to paste from the clipboard I get the following error:

```
paste: Error executing lua: vim/_editor.lua:0: Vim:E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off^@stack traceback:^@^I[C]: in function 'nvim_put'^@^Ivim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.
lua:0
```

[image]

I tried setting `set modifiable` in my `.vimrc` file but this those note solve this issue. This is what my `.vimrc` looks like:

```
" Leader
let mapleader = " "

set backspace=2   " Backspace deletes like most programs in insert mode
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile    " http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/18739402579/global-gitignore#comment-458413287
set history=50
set ruler         " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd       " display incomplete commands
set incsearch     " do incremental searching
set laststatus=2  " Always display the status line
set autowrite     " Automatically :write before running commands
set nofixeol      " Remove new lines at the end of files
set modifiable

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if (&t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")) && !exists("syntax_on")
  syntax on
endif

if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.bundles"))
  source ~/.vimrc.bundles
endif

" Load matchit.vim, but only if the user hasn't installed a newer version.
if !exists('g:loaded_matchit') && findfile('plugin/matchit.vim', &rtp) ==# ''
  runtime! macros/matchit.vim
endif

filetype plugin indent on

augroup vimrcEx
  autocmd!

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it for commit messages, when the position is invalid, or when
  " inside an event handler (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if &ft != 'gitcommit' && line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal g`\"" |
    \ endif

  " Set syntax highlighting for specific file types
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.md set filetype=markdown
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile .{jscs,jshint,eslint}rc set filetype=json
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile aliases.local,zshrc.local,*/zsh/configs/* set filetype=sh
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile gitconfig.local set filetype=gitconfig
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile tmux.conf.local set filetype=tmux
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile vimrc.local set filetype=vim
augroup END

" ALE linting events
augroup ale
  autocmd!

  if g:has_async
    set updatetime=1000
    let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 0
    autocmd CursorHold * call ale#Queue(0)
    autocmd CursorHoldI * call ale#Queue(0)
    autocmd InsertEnter * call ale#Queue(0)
    autocmd InsertLeave * call ale#Queue(0)
  else
    echoerr "The thoughtbot dotfiles require NeoVim or Vim 8"
  endif
augroup END

" When the type of shell script is /bin/sh, assume a POSIX-compatible
" shell for syntax highlighting purposes.
let g:is_posix = 1

" Softtabs, 2 spaces
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set shiftround
set expandtab

" Display extra whitespace
set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·,nbsp:·

" Use one space, not two, after punctuation.
set nojoinspaces

" Use The Silver Searcher https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher
if executable('ag')
  " Use Ag over Grep
  set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor

  " Use ag in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag --literal --files-with-matches --nocolor --hidden -g "" %s'

  " ag is fast enough that CtrlP doesn't need to cache
  let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0

  if !exists(":Ag")
    command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
    nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
  endif
endif

" Make it obvious where 80 characters is
set textwidth=80
set colorcolumn=+1

" Numbers
set number
set numberwidth=5

" Tab completion
" will insert tab at beginning of line,
" will use completion if not at beginning
set wildmode=list:longest,list:full
function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
        return "\<Tab>"
    else
        return "\<C-p>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <Tab> <C-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<CR>
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-n>

" Switch between the last two files
nnoremap <Leader><Leader> <C-^>

" Get off my lawn
nnoremap <Left> :echoe "Use h"<CR>
nnoremap <Right> :echoe "Use l"<CR>
nnoremap <Up> :echoe "Use k"<CR>
nnoremap <Down> :echoe "Use j"<CR>

" vim-test mappings
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t :TestFile<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>s :TestNearest<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>l :TestLast<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>a :TestSuite<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>gt :TestVisit<CR>
" Run commands that require an interactive shell
nnoremap <Leader>r :RunInInteractiveShell<Space>

" Treat <li> and <p> tags like the block tags they are
let g:html_indent_tags = 'li\|p'
let g:NERDTreeNodeDelimiter = "\u00a0"
" Open new split panes to right and bottom, which feels more natural
set splitbelow
set splitright

" Quicker window movement
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
" Move between linting errors
nnoremap ]r :ALENextWrap<CR>
nnoremap [r :ALEPreviousWrap<CR>

" Keybindings 

vnoremap <Leader>c "*y
noremap <Leader>v "*p
noremap <Leader>Y "+y
noremap <Leader>P "+p

" Set spellfile to location that is guaranteed to exist, can be symlinked to
" Dropbox or kept in Git and managed outside of thoughtbot/dotfiles using rcm.
set spellfile=$HOME/.vim-spell-en.utf-8.add

" Autocomplete with dictionary words when spell check is on
set complete+=kspell

" Always use vertical diffs
set diffopt+=vertical

" Map GFiles to  control p
noremap <C-p> :GFiles<CR>

" Local config
if filereadable($HOME . "/.vimrc.local")
  source ~/.vimrc.local
endif

" Autoread when changes made
:set autoread
```

it seems that this has been fixed in neovim but I still see the error raised https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/17189

Im on neovim version `NVIM v0.7.0`